# Bootstrap tooltip not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

Bootstrap Tooltip not working in chrome, but working fine in firefox.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
 if ($("[rel=tooltip]").length) {
 jQuery("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip({
placement: 'right',
trigger: "hover"
});
 }
});
</script>
```

And also the placement is not working correctly in firefox, even after defining as right, its showing only on top.

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4HptX/2/

Comment: can you update the jsfiddle to recreate the case... also the versions of jQuery and bootstrap used

Comment: Bootstrap version - v2.2.1, jQuery - v1.6.3

Comment: Is it something with versions? Not working correctly in chrome? However i loaded it with new version of Bootstrap 3.0 and Jquery 2.0 using CDN, but also not working in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your jQuery to at least 1.7 because it looks like bootstrap 2.2.1 is using `.on()`.

Look at your browser console, it is throwing an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'

Comment: Is showing error as     'Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'styleSwitcher''

Comment: But i am indirectly calling it from CDN, so that should fix the issue right? jQuery 2.0

Comment: can you share the links... the cdn links will give the versions

Comment: @user2695925 jquery 2.0.0 and bootstrap 2.2.1 seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4HptX/3/

Comment: can you also share the bootstrap link

Comment: //netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: Are you testing in chrome? Because its working fine in firefox

Comment: @user2695925 also can you check whether this sample is working for you http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4HptX/4/

Comment: Should i define bootstrap.css link also? Its showing Bootstrap v2.3.2

Comment: @user2695925 did you check the link I posted above

Answer (score 1):

Quite an old question but I've been coming across this issue today where none of these answers applied to my problem.
My problem was, that I've been using a tooltip on a disabled button, which is not possible according to the documentation of Bootstrap:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/tooltips/#disabled-elements

To handle that case, a wrapper element must be used, where the tooltip is applied to. For instance:

```
<span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Disabled tooltip">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" style="pointer-events: none;" type="button" disabled>Disabled button</button>
</span>
```

Also important is to use the `style="pointer-events: none;"` attribute on the disabled button. Otherwise it won't be working in Chrome neither. (Firefox seems to deal with it without the wrapper too.)