# Bootstrap 3.0 Popovers and tooltips

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Bootstrap and I'm having trouble getting the popover and tooltip features to work. I had no problem with the drop downs and models but I seem to be missing something for the popover and tooltips.

I am getting tooltips to show up but they are not styled and located like the bootstrap examples. And the popover is not working at all.

Please take a look and let me know what I am missing.

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="../../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
          <script src="../../assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
      </head>
      <body>
       <p id="tool"class="muted" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
        Tight pants next level keffiyeh
        <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Default tooltip">you probably</a> haven't heard of them. Photo booth beard raw denim letterpress vegan messenger bag stumptown. Farm-to-table seitan, mcsweeney's fixie sustainable quinoa 8-bit american apparel <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Another tooltip">have a</a> terry richardson vinyl chambray. Beard stumptown, cardigans banh mi lomo thundercats. Tofu biodiesel williamsburg marfa, four loko mcsweeney's cleanse vegan chambray. A really ironic artisan <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Another one here too">whatever keytar</a>, scenester farm-to-table banksy Austin <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="The last tip!">twitter handle</a> freegan cred raw denim single-origin coffee viral.</p>
       <h3>Live demo</h3>
        <div style="padding-bottom: 24px;">
          <a id="pop" href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="A Title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?">Click to toggle popover</a>
        </div>

        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('.tool').tooltip();
                $('.btn').popover();

            }); //END $(document).ready()

        </script>

        <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>

      </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: I just posted the same question a few minutes ago, also using BS3 with everything else working like Modals and Tabs but no Tooltips or Popovers... will update you should I find something.

Comment: for popover, **options** is not defined

Comment: For now I was just trying to get the default behavior but I am interested in making it show on hover instead of click but that was next. Do I still need to put something in for options?

Comment: The code above is what I am currently using and it is still not working. Any suggestions? Do I have thing in the wrong order or something?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Turns out that [Evan Larsen has the best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18411591/463065).

[Working jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/LhZpX/)

Using Evan's trick, you can instantiate all tooltips with one line of code:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({'placement': 'top'});
```

You will see that all tooltips in your long paragraph have working tooltips with just that one line.

In the jsFiddle example (link above), I also added a situation where one tooltip (by the Sign-In button) is ON by default. Also, the tooltip code is ADDED to the button in jQuery, not in the HTML markup.

---

Popovers *do* work the same as the tooltips:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({trigger: 'hover','placement': 'top'});
```

---

And there you have it! Success at last.

One of the biggest problems in figuring this stuff out was making bootstrap work with jsFiddle... Here's what you must do:

1. Get reference for Twitter Bootstrap CDN from here: http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/
2. Paste each link into notepad and strip out ALL except the URL. For example:
   **//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css**
3. In jsFiddle, on left side, open the External Resources accordion dropdown
4. Paste in each URL, pressing plus sign after each paste
5. Now, open the "Frameworks & Extensions" accordion dropdown, and select jQuery 1.9.1 (or whichever...)

NOW you are ready to go.

Comment: in the jsFiddle, why is trigger not surrounded by single quotes but placement is?

Comment: There is no good reason, I just missed it. But it seems to work. Perhaps single-word keys do not need the quotes -- sometimes they are not required -- nevertheless, I usually put them in.

Comment: that sounds like gibberish to me.  Ha! just had to say it ;)

Comment: Can you use that method in relativity to a specific container? Instantiating all tooltips or popovers within a specific container?

Comment: Should be able to... [here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oLsqdkzq/) that demonstrates isolating one div from amongst the selection of all divs containing attribute `data-toggle="tooltip"`. In the jsFiddle example, you want to instantiate tooltips in one div, not color one div's background yellow -- so you would replace the line `$(this).css('background','yellow');` with `$(this).tooltip({'placement': 'top'});`

Answer (score 231):

I use this on all my pages to enable tooltip

```
$(function () { $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip(); });
```

Comment: But the problem is. it's not working with chrome for me. then i ended up with doing some thing http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4HptX/4/ from this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18372632/bootstrap-tooltip-not-working-in-chrome

Comment: @Md Salahuddin, so its working now, once you updated your jquery?  Are you asking a question or was that a statement?

Comment: It's just a statement. i used http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4HptX/4/ instead since this code was not working with chrome for my case.

Answer (score 27):

## Working with BOOTSTRAP 3 : Short and Simple

Check - [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CtTSV/1/)

HTML

```
<div id="myDiv">
<button class="btn btn-large btn-danger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Tooltip on top">Tooltip on top</button>    
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(function () { 
    $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip(); 
});
```

Comment: This will not work if you want to have pop over functionality for data that is loading asynchronously (ajax, angular etc) but the answer below will.

Answer (score 6):

I had to do it on DOM ready

```
$( document ).ready(function () { // this has to be done after the document has been rendered
    $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip({html: true}); // enable bootstrap 3 tooltips
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        trigger: 'hover',
        'placement': 'top',
        'show': true
    });
});
```

And change my load orders to be:

- jQuery
- jQuery UI
- Bootstrap

Comment: i had a similar issue, was loading jquery ui after bootstrap, your answer made me realize the issue with that.

Comment: check [this](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-popovers.php) for popover, **1. Triggering the Popovers , 2. Positioning of Popovers via Data Attributes**

Answer (score 5):

For some reason the only way I was able to get my code to work is by switching couple of things. If nothing worked for you so far, please give a whirl to this:

```
$('body').popover({ 
    selector: '[data-toggle="popover"]', 
    trigger: 'hover',
    placement: 'right'
});
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me since the popover element may not be in view to begin with. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to enable the tooltip:

```
$('some id or class that you add to the above a tag').popover({
    trigger: "hover" 
})
```

Comment: No, that will just display the popover itself when you hover over it, not the tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your script and, as noted by xXPhenom22Xx, you must instantiate the tooltip.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.btn-danger').tooltip();

    }); //END $(document).ready()

</script>
```

Note that I used your class "btn-danger". You can create a different class, or use an `id="someidthatimakeup"`.

Comment: Ok I have changed the code to match what you suggested, I think. It is still not working. I do not know Javascript yet so this is a little tricky. I am just trying to get the examples they have to work the same way.

Comment: The popover one is a little difficult but I got the tooltip one to work as above.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Rails and ActiveAdmin, this is going to be your problem:
https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/issues/450
Basically, a conflict with active_admin.js

This is the solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11745446/264084 (Karen's answer)
tldr: Move active_admin assets into the "vendor" directory.