# Input type's placeholder not displaying with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page with multiple `<input>` tags of type `text` like the one shown below:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="fname" id="fname" onChange="setName();" class="form-control admissionFormInput"/>
```

The placeholder is not being displayed on the webpage neither on Firefox nor on IE. When I do *inspect element* on the input the placeholder attribute itself is not present. If I manually add the attribute over there then the placeholder text displays fine. What is the issue here? Is this due to browser or Bootstrap?

EDIT 2: Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/LhZpX/2043/

As you can see, the HTML code contains placeholder and is correctly displayed. However on opening the file in my browser and doing inspect element on inputs, the placeholder attribute itself is missing. I have one more page with bootstrap used and that displays placeholder just fine.

Comment: it shows there on firefox, however you added it two times.

Comment: sorry, I only added it twice here, not in actual code. Edited.

Comment: Post a complete code example that we can use to reproduce the problem please.

Comment: @j08691 I have included a pastebin link.

Comment: You need to spend some time narrowing that code block down. No one is going to want to wade through that looking for your bug.

Comment: @j08691 you can tell me exactly what you want. The whole code is just html. COnsider just a single `input` tag in the body.

Comment: Well, the first issue is that your pastebin has no elements that actually have a placeholder attribute. But if there were any, I'd start by removing the CSS and JavaScript and add them back one at a time and see when the problem emerges.

Comment: Yeah, what j08691 said--your pastebin code does not have any placeholders in it at all. Post the code you're using that has the placeholders. Better yet, create a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net), or a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/new)

Comment: Feel free to use [the jsFiddle in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410922/bootstrap-3-0-popovers-and-tooltips/18537617#18537617) as the basis of your code example -- it has bootstrap libraries pre-loaded -- and you can see a working example of bootstrap tooltips.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Firefox on Windows shows the placeholders just fine.

Comment: Firefox on Windows. Neither do they show up in IE and nor in inspect element, like I never wrote them! Like I said, the other pages show it just fin thoug.